# Format values of a Pie Chart in Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using pie chart from **Charts** library for iOS and have been able to display the results on the chart but i am unable to format the value in that chart.

**Expected Output**

I want the value as £ appended before the value. Just like this - £ 10

**What I've Done**

```
class ChartValueFormatter : NSObject, IValueFormatter {

    var numberFormatter : NumberFormatter?

    convenience init(numberFormatter : NumberFormatter) {
        self.init()
        self.numberFormatter = numberFormatter
    }

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String{
        return numberFormatter!.string(for: "£ \(value)")!
    }

}

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
let valuesFormatter = ChartValueFormatter(numberFormatter: numberFormatter)             
dataSet.valueFormatter = valuesFormatter
```

**Actual Problem**

This approach is giving me error on `return numberFormatter!.string(for: "£ \(value)")!` and the error is because the `value` is `nil`.

Can anyone please help me on what i've done wrong and what should be done in order to get the expected output.

Comment: May i know why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this:

```
let price:Float = 1.99

extension Float {
    var asLocaleCurrency:String {
        var formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.currencyCode = "GBP"
        return formatter.string(for: self)!
    }
}

let pri = price.asLocaleCurrency
print(pri)
```

Result: £1.99

you should use

```
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
```

not as .decimal

Comment: Amazing solution but do you know how can i set that for my `dataset`?

Comment: in your case you value is double you need to update the extension for Double. I guess solutions makes sense?